# Preventing translating child 3D View in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Is there any way to prevent translating child 3D view in Model Derivative API?

As you can see in the following image, I don't want to see that child view in my document browser.

[image: Document Browser]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to customize which viewable can be translated. All the available viewables will be translated.

As an ad-hoc method, you can remove that document browser UI element.

Comment: I uploaded the same model file in viewer.autodesk.com then by means of the browser console I enabled Document Browser. What I saw was interesting. The extra views were not were there! Any idea?

Comment: in the left vertical menu, you get all the viewables

Comment: it could be modified, in documentation, there are no options for customizing, it shows all the available by default. so you have to do it on your own.